# Detect broken links in a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, broken-links

Is there any way to make a post-render check for the links in a react component, check them with a callback, and render them as broken if the check in the callback fails? I have found `broken-link-checker` but I do not think that this library fits to what I am trying to do

Comment: Why is the library not fitting? Its description matches your question.

Comment: @JulienD it just detects the links and informs which of them are broken I want to somehow parse the react's component DOM and check the `href` manually and change the `<a>` element as red

Comment: It has a callback that executes when it finds a broken link.